# Envio de notificação push através de um array

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, push-notification

Estou com um problema ao enviar notificação push para vários usuários ao mesmo tempo, eu tenho uma pagina de envio mais ela está enviando apenas para um único token eu gostaria de saber como fazer com que ela envie para um array de tokens cadastrados, segue o código.

```
<?php
$message = ucfirst($_POST['txtmensagem']);
if (!empty($message)){

  $deviceToken ='aa798429fa852e1d593c7c4d9360293da2b3c9704d044dd8a8fcd693e2260170';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'senhaaqui'; //pushchat

// Put your alert message here:


$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');//ck.pem
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'conteudo' => 'aqui o conteudo',
    'comando' => 'video',
    'badgecount' => '1'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa enviar uma notificação de cada vez.

Faça um looping com os tokens e envie individualmente.

Você pode usar essa lib para facilitar [apns-php](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/downloads/list)

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sou expert em PHP mas aparentemente essa lógica está certa. Para você fazer o disparo pra vários, você vai ter que tirar o valor do  `$deviceToken` que está hardcoded e atribui-lo através de variável. Depois é só jogar em um bloco de repetição, pois ele já está abrindo e fechando a conexão com a gateway corretamente.

Uma boa idéia é vc encapsular isso em uma função, passando o device token como argumento. Assim você consegue usar esse código em um loop p/ fazer o disparo.

Se for fazer isso mesmo, faça um callback também para você saber se o push foi disparado ou não.

Mais uma coisa, **NÃO ESQUEÇA** de mudar o valor do endereço da gateway (que também está hardcoded), quando for colocar em produção, senão nenhuma notificação vai ser disparada.